# Bootstrap 3.1.1 : Product slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display a  product slider in my bootstrap 3.1.1 site just like [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-product-cart-slider) 
 or [this](http://codepen.io/gumetis/pen/pbLyD) problem is that when i add given html and css as  and press right left arrow to slide products they are  moved to next 4 products but sliding effect is never there only text and image change as i click next/ pre arrow. i added bootstrap js  and jquery

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

i copied all the code as per given directions but it is still not showing required slide effect can someone help me with it whats missing . Code can be seen from given links

Comment: can you make a plunker or a jsfiddle?

Comment: i copied exact code from here http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-product-cart-slider

Comment: why are you using two different versions of jquery, also jquery needs to come before bootstrap

Comment: my problem is  that all sliders are doing same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load jQuery, and just one version, before Bootstrap.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins need jQuery loaded first for them to work.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try it? Add **https:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```